# Git not ignoring some files extensions in my .gitignore file. Why?

Tags: git, gitignore

In my .gitignore I have...

```
*.xcuserstate
*.xcbkptlist
```

However, whenever I open XCode and change anything, git annoys me telling me these have changed (which obviously they have)... but they are apart of my .gitignore... so why are they being flagged to begin with?

Comment: Were these files already staged when you modified the `.gitignore` file?  Where is this `gitignore` file located?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   They've been apart of the committed project for some time as I didn't ignore these files when I started. The gitignore is alongside my .git and all project files locally.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  What does `git status` show you from the project root?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right now, because I've opened xcode and that's altered these files, they are under the not staged for commit. They typically get committed often though, as I might have 40 files during one commit, and instead of adding each separately, I do a wholesale add, commit, and push.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for Git Ignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (emphasis mine):

> The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files *not* tracked by Git *remain* untracked.
>
> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.

Your Xcode Git plugin keeps telling you about the files in question because it is still tracking them.  You need to do a `git rm --cached <filename>` on the file *before* adding it to `.gitignore` if you want the latter to take effect.